# Can I add the ubuntu desktop gui for disk decryption to ubuntu server?

Tags: server, lvm

I have an automatic install with cloud-config that takes the ubuntu-server image and adds ubuntu-desktop as a package. But I noticed the LVM decryption has a nice gui if you just install ubuntu desktop via its designated image while with the server image you have to fill in the password in the commandline. Is there a way to have this gui on the server version as well since our users are used to this and it looks way beter for an end product?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after some researching I found out that the solution is to edit the `/etc/default/grub` file. The entry `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` controls the display of the splash screen.

Adding the word `splash` enables the splash screen with condensed text output and adding `quiet` keyword results in only displaying the splash screen.

By default ubuntu-server has none of these keywords

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

While ubuntu desktops default is to add both

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

after editing the file grub needs to be updated by running

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

In my case since I am doing an automatic install and I don't really want to have to do this for each of the new installs, I added following lines to my cloud-config file:

```
user-data:
  runcmd:
   - sudo sed -i 's/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"/' /etc/default/grub
   - sudo update-grub
```